# is it possible to restrict printer tray usage on a printer using AD Group membership?

Tags: active-directory, printing, restrictions

I have a multi tray laserjet printer that has a drawer dedicated to printing checks. I was curious if I could use Active Directory Group Membership to restrict who can print from that drawer to minimize the amount of checks wasted?

I would fully restrict access to the printer but I would like to use it as a fail over backup in that area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the configuration abilities of the printer driver, it may be possible to make several printer shares with fixed settings, like say "Printer A plain paper", and one "Printer A checks".

You would then assign different permissions to the different printer shares. This of course requires the use of a print server that is AD aware.

I know this works with certain Xerox or Canon high-end printers.

Comment: what your saying makes sense. I'll give it a shot.